# PyRRD-0.1.0: how to call RRD.bufferValue() with data tuple?

Tags: python, rrdtool

The **PyRRD** doc says to call `rrd.update(timestamp, value1, value2, ...)`
rather than listing each single value in the parameter list, I would like to call `update()` with a tuple, already containing the values:

```
myValueTuple=[10,11,12,13]
rrd.update(timestamp, myValueTuple)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is provided by pythons native capability to expand a tuple into an argument list, by adding an asterisk "*" in front of the tuple:

> rrd.update(timestamp, *myValueTuple)